# error with a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm creating a form to insert data to logement table and lit table and also table espace.
i'm trying to insert data in all this tables that are connected like in the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xDDT.png)

but i'm getting this error :

```
Warning: mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in F:\-- SOFTWARE\WEB-SERVER\esyphp\ep0002\data\localweb\school\buckup\BU-Projet\0008\ajoutez.php on line 88
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO logement(Titre, AdresseLogement, Prix, NombrePerson, idTypeLogement) VALUES ('hgfrte','125669 hgfer','1236','33',''). Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yandexd`.`logement`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Logement_idTypeLogement` FOREIGN KEY (`idTypeLogement`) REFERENCES `typedelogement` (`idTypeLogement`)) ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO lit(idLit, TypeDeLit) VALUES ('','kanape, canape'). Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yandexd`.`lit`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Lit_idLogement` FOREIGN KEY (`idLogement`) REFERENCES `logement` (`idLogement`))
```

my php code is

```html
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yandexd");
 
// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

 switch ($_POST['logm-type']) {
    case "Maison":
        $_POST['logm-type'] = 1;
        break;
    case "Appartement":
        $_POST['logm-type'] = 2;
        break;
    case "Chambre_privée":
        $_POST['logm-type'] = 3;
        break;
    case "Chambre_partagée":
        $_POST['logm-type'] = 4;
        break;
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO logement(Titre, AdresseLogement, Prix, NombrePerson, idTypeLogement)
 VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-titre']."','".$_POST['logm-adresse']."','".$_POST['logm-prix']."','".$_POST['logm-personne']."','".$_POST['logm-type']."')";


$thelogm_id = mysql_insert_id( $link );

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO espace(TypeDEspace, idLogement)
 VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-espace']."','".$thelogm_id."')";


$sql2 = "INSERT INTO lit(TypeDeLit, idLogement)
 VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-typelit']."','".$thelogm_id."')";   


if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Le logement est ajouté.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql1)){
    echo "Le logement est ajouté.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql1. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){
    echo "Le logement est ajouté.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql2. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
 
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
}
        else {
```

I tried all solution found on stackoverflow, but i can't solve the problem

Comment: Your error mentions `mysql` while you are using `mysqli` did you check that?

Comment: Yes, you are using MySQL as your database engine, but mysql_insert_id() is not a valid function for mysqli.

Comment: In your code it says `$link = @mysqli_connect(`, `mysqli_connect_error(` and so on. So in short you are not using `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

If the client sends you a string in `logm-type` that doesn't exactly match one of the four you've mentioned in your `switch` statement, your code will pass the string they gave you as if it was the ID, in which case the error message you're seeing is the best case scenario.

Your code is using POST values in SQL queries directly, which is not a good idea - what if the client (accidentally or deliberately) includes an apostrophe?

Comment: this is a  comment not an answer

Comment: First paragraph is the answer. Second was just an attempt at advice that seemed relevant.

Answer (score 0):

now i changed the code to

```html
$sql = "INSERT INTO logement(Titre, AdresseLogement, Prix, NombrePerson, idTypeLogement)
  VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-titre']."','".$_POST['logm-adresse']."','".$_POST['logm-prix']."','".$_POST['logm-personne']."','".$_POST['logm-type']."')";


$thelogm_id = mysql_insert_id( $link );

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO espace(TypeDEspace, idLogement)
  VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-espace']."','".$thelogm_id."')";


$sql2 = "INSERT INTO lit(TypeDeLit, idLogement)
  VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-typelit']."','".$thelogm_id."')";
```

but i did received this error

Warning: mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in F:-- SOFTWARE\WEB-SERVER\esyphp\ep0002\data\localweb\school\buckup\BU-Projet\0008\ajoutez.php on line 87
Le logement est ajouté.Le logement est ajouté.ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO lit(TypeDeLit, idLogement) VALUES ('sofa, canape, lit',''). Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`yandexd`.`lit`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Lit_idLogement` FOREIGN KEY (`idLogement`) REFERENCES `logement` (`idLogement`))

Comment: You should add changes you make, to your original post not add them as an answer. Please remove this answer.

Comment: how i do remove it

Answer (score 0):

Your calling mysql_insert_id out of sequence. 
It returns the generated ID from the last successful query, which means you have to execute $sql first.

Try this:

```
// this declares the sql query, but hasn't executed it. 
$sql = "INSERT INTO logement(Titre, AdresseLogement, Prix, NombrePerson, idTypeLogement)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-titre']."','".$_POST['logm-adresse']."','".$_POST['logm-prix']."','".$_POST['logm-personne']."','".$_POST['logm-type']."')";

// this executes the sql.  Now mysql_insert_id can fetch the id. 
if(mysql_query($link, $sql)){
    echo "Le logement est ajouté.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}

// call mysql_insert_id after executing $sql, otherwise you'll just get null
$thelogm_id = mysql_insert_id( $link );
if( is_null($thelogm_id)){
    echo "ERROR: no id".
}

$sql1 = "INSERT INTO espace(TypeDEspace, idLogement)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-espace']."','".$thelogm_id."')";


$sql2 = "INSERT INTO lit(TypeDeLit, idLogement)
    VALUES ('".$_POST['logm-typelit']."','".$thelogm_id."')";  

if(mysqli_query($link, $sql1)){
    echo "Le logement est ajouté.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql1. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
```

Be aware, if the query for $sql fails you'll not want to execute $sql1 and $sql2.

Comment: i'm getting this error : Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in F:\-- SOFTWARE\WEB-SERVER\esyphp\ep0002\data\localweb\school\buckup\BU-Projet\0010\ajoutez.php on line 88
ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO logement(Titre, AdresseLogement, Prix, NombrePerson, idTypeLogement) VALUES ('best house','123 moncton','500','6','4').
Warning: mysql_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in F:\-- SOFTWARE\WEB-SERVER\esyphp\ep0002\data\localweb\school\buckup\BU-Projet\0010\ajoutez.php on line 95
ERROR: no idLe logement est ajouté.

Comment: as others have pointed out, you're connecting with mysqli_connect.  This returns a mysqli OBJECT.  You either need to convert your code to use mysqli or create your connection with mysql_connect() which returns a REFERENCE.   Here is a link to the mysqli php page http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.  If this isn't an option for you change @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yandexd"); to  @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yandexd").